# Can you add a second hard drive to a Dell XPS M1530?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, dell-xps

I'm looking to add more storage after getting an SSD in my Dell XPS M1530, and I was wondering if there was some way to add a second hard drive, maybe in place of the CD drive as I've heard is possible in some MacBooks? So, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to get a CD drive bay insert that allow a second hard drive.  For example [this](http://newmodeus.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=311).  It should be available from other vendors - I've seen them on eBay.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the service manual for your laptop at

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/xps-m1530/manuals

The service manual tells you how to get the CD drive out, it's possible but it requires the removal of quite a few other components first. Also the service manual assumes you will be replacing the drive with a dell spare part that presumablly already has the mounting hardware attatched, so it doesn't go into removing the mounting hardware from the drive and attatching it to a new one. I suspect that this removal/reattachment is fairly simple but I can't gaurantee it.

You would then need an adaptor to mount a hard drive in the optical drive bay. Unfortunately there is more than one type of optical drive and hence more than one type of adaptor. Other than taking the drive out and measuring it i'm not sure of any good way to make sure you get the right one.